# Combine rows into single column in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

Does anyone know how to combine rows into a single column in Oracle?  For example, say I have this table:

```
Customer   Bought
----------------------------
John       laptops
John       Phones
Lisa       Watches
```

I want a query to produce the following format:

```
Customer     CustomerBought
------------------------------------------
John         Laptops, Phones
Lisa         Watches
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at LISTAGG or WM_CONCAT function.

Comment: Next time you add tables in a question, select the table and hit Ctrl+K. It then indents the whole block with 4 spaces, which maintains the newlines and uses monospaced characters.

Comment: Question... did you tag this as Oracle 11g, or did the system do it for you? And, related - if in fact you are on Oracle 11, is it version 11.1 or 11.2? Often that won't matter, but `LISTAGG()` as used in Patrick's solution (which is absolutely the perfect answer) was only introduced in 11.2. If you are on 11.1 you are out of luck, you will need a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data_qry (name, item)
as
(select 'John', 'Laptop' from dual union all
 select 'John', 'Phone' from dual union all
 select 'Lisa', 'Watches' from dual union all
 select 'Lisa', 'Glasses' from dual
 )
 select name, listagg(item, ', ') within group (order by item) as items
 from data_qry
 group by name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  LISTAGG() is what I need.  I'm on Oracle 12c.  Thanks again.